# Rest Server or API to test my Restful client?

Tags: android, rest, web

I am creating an Android app that requires me to do a rest request to a server, get some data and analyze them.

I  am still new to android development so i am not sure if i am implementing the requests and threading right, and the server is not ready yet. So i need a public rest server that i can use to test sending requests? It doesn't matter what data i receive.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test against any public REST API that you can find from famous services and choose actions that don't require an authentication. For instance [Tiny Url](http://scripting.com/stories/2007/06/27/tinyurlHasAnApi.html) (if you want to test GET requests) and if you want more complex data you can get an auth token from Twitter and test against [their API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api).

Note that this is just an example. The idea is to investigate the APIs of your favorite sites/servies and you'll likely find one that fits you and your tests.

Answer (score 7):

There is a testing web called httpbin, it's used by requests python library (same author).

> Testing an HTTP Library can become difficult sometimes. PostBin.org is fantastic for testing POST requests, but not much else. This exists to cover all kinds of HTTP scenarios. Additional endpoints are being considered (e.g. /deflate).

https://httpbin.org/

Answer (score 3):

If it's just a GET request, the easiest thing to do is just find a text file or an image on the web (such as this random image http://www.databison.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/conversion-of-excel-in-fixed-width-text-file-format.png) and point you code to that. Check you are getting a 200 response code, and are receiving the data back.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Ruby on Rails and generate a basic RESTful resource like that:

```
rails new restweb && cd restweb
rails generate scaffold post title:string body:string
```

Then launch the local app server:

```
rails server
```

Then test your library with this url : http://127.0.0.1:3000/posts (.json)

Comment: A bit extreme to install a whole framework for testing purposes only. But I'd do the same given I am a Ruby/Rails enthusiast but that's not necessarily his case :)

Comment: I will surely do that, but later on cause i am on a tight schedule. Amokrane provided me with a quicker fix, Voted up anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.mockable.io/ allows you to specify the response and view recent requests history.

http://www.mocky.io/ is a bit faster to setup but you don't see client requests made.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using SOAPUi (yes I know it is intended for SOAP ws), at least [that is what they say in their page](http://www.soapui.org/Service-Mocking/mocking-rest-services.html). Also checkout out the article [Simple server mock for REST services](http://blog.xebia.com/2011/08/10/simple-server-mock-for-rest-services/) by Michaël van Leeuwen.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [apigee.com](http://apigee.com) - they have an awesome console for investigating APIs (you can find one that doesn't require authentication) and then you can hit that API with your code and get the same responses you see in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Rest service for testing: [jsonplaceholder.com](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try out getsandbox.com. It works like a charm and gives to tons of functionality etc.